# Approximate CO2 emissions for shipping a parcel from one location to another

Tags: carbon-footprint

First of all, I know it is impossible to answer this question accurately. But that is not the point. An approximation will suffice.

For a project I need to display the CO<sub>2</sub> "cost" for shipping a parcel. It primarily involves shipping parcels between Western European countries, but occasionally there will be some parcels going to Canada and the US as well.

So, how can I approach this with a fairly simple calculation?

Comment: Two related questions with pieces of the answer: [Lowest impact transatlantic crossing](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/829/3379) and [What is the share of global human CO2 emission of cargo transport by ship?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/2857/3379)

Comment: Do you know anything about how the parcels are transported? Overseas by plane or boat? Within Europe by train and truck, or only by truck?

Comment: Weight and volume of the parcel? Transport method (probably in bulk by container)?

Comment: @THelper I will double check, but I am sure the large majority is transported either by train/truck/van.

Comment: @JanDoggen At least 90% will be relatively small packages of between 30x20x10 and 60x40x30 cm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Carbon intensity by shipping method

The World Shipping Council provides this chart showing [approximate carbon emissions by shipping method](http://www.worldshipping.org/industry-issues/environment/air-emissions/carbon-emissions):

> [image]

### Shipping emissions calculators

If that's too approximate, there are a number of different calculators you can try out:

- The Carbon Fund [Business Calculator](https://www.carbonfund.org/business-calculator/)

The last tab calculates annual emissions based on quantity, weight, and distance of packages shipped. It's annualized, which is annoying, but it's the only one of the three that includes air freight (and zeppelin!).

- OOCL [supply chain carbon calculator](https://www.oocl.com/eng/aboutoocl/Environmentalcare/ooclcarboncalculator/Pages/default.aspx)

OOCL is a Hong Kong-based logistics and shipping company. This calculator breaks down results by shipping method, but only seems to work for major ports.

> [image]

- CN [Carbon Calculator](https://www.cn.ca/en/delivering-responsibly/environment/emissions/carbon-calculator/)

CN is a Canadian railway operator. This calculator seems like the most useful of all. You enter the major ports for shipping distances, then add additional distances that the cargo will travel by train or truck.

> [image]

Comment: Do you know if the weight of the ship itself is accounted for in the calculations?

Comment: @clapas this would directly affect fuel efficiency, so I'd assume so. A heavier ship, all else being equal, would use more fuel, and fuel use is what's actually being measured.